# Junit : Runlistener overriden method (testFinished) not called when running a Parameterized test

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized

I have a requirement to run a parameterized test which is working fine as expected , but the concern here is , In our framework we have our own custom listener class which extends RunListener and overrides all methods . but none of the methods is overriden when i run the test as a parameterized test . but the same works fine if i run a test without a parameters .

below is my CustomJunitListener

```
{
/**
 * Class used to do some report regarding the JUnit event notifier
 */
public class CustomJUnitListener extends RunListener {

  SeleniumTest test = null;

  public void setSeleniumTest(SeleniumTest test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    if (test != null) {
      test.postExecution();
    }
  }



}
```

the method postExection is not called when i run a paramterized test . I want postExection method to be called after completion of each set of parameters for a test.

Below is my selenium test

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test_Script extends SeleniumTest{

  private String testName;
  private String from;
  private String to;

  public Test_Script(String testName , String from, String to) {
    this.testName =testName;
    this.from =from;
    this.to =to;
  }

  @Test
  public void scenario()throws Exception{
     /* Test Script */
  }

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> getData() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    XMLReader reader = new XMLReader("NewFile.xml");
    return reader.readXML();
  }
```

Please provide me your inputs on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the way to use a RunListener. RunListener is independent from the test - you add it to the class that is running your test (in your case the Parameterized class), not your test itself. For an example of how to use RunListener, see [How to add listener in Junit testcases](http://howtodoinjava.com/tag/runlistener/).

However, I suspect this isn't actually what you want. You probably want to look at TestRules, specifically the ExternalResource class. This allows you to define a before() and after() method that you can reuse more easily:

```
@Rule ExternalResource myRule = new ExternalResource() {
    public void after() {
        test.postExecution();
    }
}
```

For more information, see [JUnit wiki - Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules)

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your inputs , i really apreciate your immediate response , it solved my problem .  Also as u said our Runlistener is independent from test , i just posted in my comment for better understandings